# change event not firing on select menu in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Here is the code I have written so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Registration</title>
    <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True"/>
    <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="YES" />
    <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="YES" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="my.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#mothertongue').live("change",function() {

   alert($(this).val());
});​

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" data-theme="e" id="page3" data-add-back-btn="true">
        <div  data-theme="e" data-role="header">
            <h3></h3>
            <a href="index.html" class="ui-btn-right" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext"
            data-direction="reverse">Home</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" style="padding: 15px">




                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="selectmenu3">
                        <p>
                            Mother Tongue
                        </p> </label>
                    <select name="mothertongue" id="mothertongue" >
                        <option selected="selected" value="-1">Select Mother Tongue</option>
                        <option value="Telugu">Telugu</option>
                        <option value="Kannada">Kannada</option>
                        <option value="Hindi">Hindi</option>
                        <option value="Marathi">Marathi</option>
                        <option value="Tamil">Tamil</option>
                        <option value="Assamese">Assamese</option>
                        <option value="Bengali" >Bengali</option>
                        <option value="Coorgi">Coorgi</option>
                        <option value="Dogri">Dogri</option>
                        <option value="English">English</option>
                        <option value="Garhwali">Garhwali</option>
                        <option value="Gujarati">Gujarati</option>
                        <option value="Kashmiri">Kashmiri</option>
                        <option value="Konkani">Konkani</option>
                        <option value="Kumaoni">Kumaoni</option>
                        <option value="Kutchi">Kutchi</option>
                        <option value="Magahi">Maithili</option>
                        <option value="Malayalam">Malayalam</option>
                        <option value="Manipuri">Manipuri</option>
                        <option value="Marwari">Marwari</option>
                        <option value="Nepali">Nepali</option>
                        <option value="Oriya">Oriya</option>
                        <option value="Punjabi">Punjabi</option>
                        <option value="Sindhi">Sindhi</option>
                        <option value="Tulu">Tulu</option>
                        <option value="Urdu">Urdu</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                </div>


        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

the change event for mothertongue is not firing at all. I have written this script for the change event but it doesn't fire at all.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#mothertongue').live("change",function() {

   alert($(this).val());
});​

    </script>
```

I have been pulling my hair all night over this issue. Please help me or else I may become bald :(

Comment: What errors are you getting in your Console? The code you have is perfectly fine, it must be something in your JS files above it that is breaking it (and why it's not working)

Comment: I am not getting any errors at all..the alert simply doesn't show up :(

Comment: I even removed my.js then also it doesn't show up...stupid jquery mobile grrrrr....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at 
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-equivalent-of-document-ready

and use something like

```
$('#PageId').live('pagecreate', function() {
    $('#element').click(function () {
        //Do something
    });
});
```

And important that code must be placed between you link to Jquery library and jquery.mobile, eg:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/lib/jquery-1.7.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>MobileInit();</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/lib/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: http://navaneet.opilane.com/mobile/registration.html please check this link ..i have hosted it on my live server ..please click on the mother tongue menu ..nothing works for it :(

Comment: I can't see your script tag on the page. you may try to move script tag inside div with data-role=content. Jqm cut head of the page, but only for ajax calls... however

Comment: pheww finally got it running guys...thanks to all of you for sticking with me on this...this is why i love stackoverflow...its like a family which understands programmers :)

Comment: felix waht you said gave me an idea so i moved my js file inside content and voila it worked..so why was it not working previously ??? and do i have to move my js always inside the content

Comment: nal and felix can you both please elaborate when jqm cuts the head for ajax calls, cause actually in the main index page i was prefetching the registration page that is this page through ajax only ...so did it mess with my js file ???

Comment: It's better for you to get familiar with the documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html. If short: Query has removed all the script in the head of the page. Yes, you should place script in the content tag, or use on of the init events of JQM.

Comment: From the link above: When that Ajax request goes out, the framework will receive its entire text content, but it will only inject the contents of the response's body element (or more specifically the data-role="page" element, if it's provided), meaning nothing in the head of the page will be used (with the exception of the page title, which is fetched specifically).

Answer (score 1):

Since you posted the link to your live page the error appears to be `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` in chrome developer console.

Open your html file in a hex editor.  Or delete and recreate all the text after the alert() call and before the body tag.

Comment: you don't need document ready for jquery mobile however what you wrote is correct for jquery but not for jquery mobile

Comment: god only knows how many method I have tried with this piece of code ...nothing works..please help me or give me poison :(

Comment: whoah, somehow missed that you were using mobile... have you tried `$(document).bind('pageinit')` instead too?

Comment: I tried my code in jsfiddle ..there it runs fine..but why not in my server check this http://jsfiddle.net/4QvX5/

Comment: @Nav, yeah your code was fine.  just some illegal invisible character in your uploaded file is the porblem

Answer (score 0):

Live is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 use "delegate" or even better "on"

http://api.jquery.com/live/

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Your problem may be the '.on' scope - #mothertongu may be too specific. Try something like :

```
$('#PageID').on("change", '#mothertongue', function() {
   ...
});​
```

Also keep in mind when submitting forms in jQuery Mobile the default is to ajax in the next page. So your code may be working on the last page but not the submission result. Take a look at http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/forms/forms-sample.html you might just need to add  data-ajax="false" to the form tag.